# Why WSO2 ESB is Encoding Email Attachment in Base64

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

My proxy service receiving email from Gmail IMAP server. Email has `csv` file attachment as well. WSO2 ESB received the email successfully but in the logs attachment content is printed as **base64** encoded string. Below are my `axis2.xml` connfigs.

```
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--                Message Formatters                 -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->

    <!-- Following content type to message formatter mapping can be used to implement support -->
    <!-- for different message format serializations in Axis2. These message formats are -->
    <!-- expected to be resolved based on the content type. -->
    <messageFormatters>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.formatters.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/plain"
                         class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>
<messageformatter contenttype="text/csv" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>
        <!--JSON Message Formatters-->
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
        <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/-->
        <!--messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/-->
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
        <!--messageFormatter contentType="text/html"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/-->
        <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/-->
        <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
        <!--messageFormatter contentType="x-application/hessian"
                         class="org.apache.synapse.format.hessian.HessianMessageFormatter"/-->
        <!--messageFormatter contentType=""
                         class="org.apache.synapse.format.hessian.HessianMessageFormatter"/-->
        <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/edi-hl7"
                         class="org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.message.HL7MessageFormatter"/-->
    </messageFormatters>

    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--                Message Builders                   -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->

    <!-- Following content type to builder mapping can be used to implement support for -->
    <!-- different message formats in Axis2. These message formats are expected to be -->
    <!-- resolved based on the content type. -->
    <messageBuilders>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>

        <!--JSON Message Builders-->
        <messagebuilder contenttype="text/csv" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
        <!--messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/-->
        <!--messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/-->
        <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/related"
                       class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
    <!--<messageBuilder contentType="multipart/related" class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MIMEBuilder"/>-->
        <!--messageBuilder contentType="application/soap+xml"
                       class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/-->
        <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain"
                       class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="text/xml"
                       class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
        <!--messageBuilder contentType="x-application/hessian"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.format.hessian.HessianMessageBuilder"/-->
        <!--messageBuilder contentType=""
                         class="org.apache.synapse.format.hessian.HessianMessageBuilder"/-->
        <!--messageBuilder contentType="application/edi-hl7"
                        class="org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.message.HL7MessageBuilder"/-->
    </messageBuilders>
```

Log:

```
INFO - LogMediator To: /services/MailService MessageID: urn:uuid:492da964-ee6c-4ae7-b444-269ba8a52641 Direction: request%%%%%%%%%%%%Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">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</ns:binary></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2017-03-22 11:16:46,049] DEBUG - RelayUtils Content Type is multipart/mixed; boundary=94eb2c1432baf6e77a054b4bb379
```

Proxy Code:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MailTransportProtocolIMAP"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="mailto">
   <target>
      <inSequence>

               <log level="full" separator="---=== Invalid Subject ===---"/>

      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.starttls.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.socketFactory.port">993</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">mapperxslt1@gmail.com</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.fetchsize">100000</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.user">mapperxslt1</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.password">Password</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.host">imap.gmail.com</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">multipart/mixed</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.MoveAfterProcess">Processed</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.port">993</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">imap</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Folder">inbox</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.ssl.enable">false</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Is there any way in WSO2 ESB to save the attachment as it is in the directory? Any help would be great favor.

Comment: I think the Problem is that you haven't defined a message builder for multipart/mixed. Therefor the default message builder is used, not sure if it's the binary. Try to add the corresponding message builder to your axis2.xml. The following link might also help to get a better understanding.  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Working+with+Message+Builders+and+Formatters

Comment: I have tried with that as well. But still it is encoding in base64.

Comment: Have you added <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter> to your proxy? I think it would be most efficent if you share your whole proxy config.

Comment: After looking at your proxy it seems to me that you're missing the corresponding message builder. I'm not sure which builder you Need to take for multipart/mixed, therefor I'd try to add the following to your axis2.xml. <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/mixed"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"/>

Comment: I've made a test a few weeks ago with the following against an pop3 Server. Maybe this also helps.   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Test_MailTo"
       transports="mailto"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="senderAddress" expression="get-property('transport', 'From')"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="Sender Address" expression="get-property('senderAddress')"/>
         </log>

Comment: <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="vfs:file:///opt/wso2/cl/pop3"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.host">pop3.server.name</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.password">myPassword</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="mail.pop3.user">myUser</parameter>

Comment: <parameter name="mail.pop3.port">110</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Address">email@domain.com</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.Protocol">pop3</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>

Answer (score 0):

You can access the content inside request/response payload of csv by registering "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder" and "org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter" as message builder and formatter for text/csv content-type.

Please add the following formatters and builders to axis2.xml. please check builder.

```
<messageformatter contenttype="text/csv" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>

<messagebuilder contenttype="text/csv" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>
```